# Spring boot not loading images from src/main/resources path into jsp

Tags: java, html, jsp, spring-boot

I have a image file inside

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38zDn.png)

Here is my configuration inside Configuration class.

```
private static final String[] CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS = {
        "classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/**",
        "classpath:/static/**", "classpath:/public/" };


public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations(CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS);
```

Inside Jsp I am not able to load the image under div tag

```
<div id="image">
        <p>
            <img src="/images/reviewCount.jpg" width="600" height="400" border="0" usemap="#chart">
        </p>
```

I tried

1) To give absolute path like src/main/resources/static/images/reviewCount.jpg

2) `src="{/images}/reviewCount.jpg"`

Both the approaches went in a wine.

Any one who can some  shed light would be appreciated.

TIA.

regards
Vinod

Answer (score 1):

You have to place all the `images, css, js` files inside your `webapp` folder.. ie `webapp/resources`.

If you are packaging the application as a **jar** then dont use the `src/main/webapp` 
this will only work with **war** packaging and it will be ignored by most build tools if you generate a jar.

In Spring boot by default, resources are mapped on `/**` but you can tune that via `spring.mvc.static-path-pattern`. For instance, relocating all resources to `/resources/**` can be achieved as follows:

```
spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/resources/**
```

Read more from [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content)

Comment: hi Jobin I agree with you but at this time I don't want to change the folder structure

Comment: updated the answer, the second option will work for you.

Comment: I am sorry did`t get it?

Comment: I your case try adding `spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/resources/static/**` to your `application.properties`

Comment: Let me try this since I have old spring boot version which doesn't support this annotation.I will upgrade and keep you posted.Thanks for your response

Answer (score 1):

Spring Boot automatically maps static folder in the resources to serve static content. Just put images like this:[image]

Comment: hi Igor if you see my screen shot I already have image in static folder but how to provide the same  path in jsp to render that image is my question.

Comment: You don't have to change anything in your JSP file. Use the same path.

Answer (score 1):

It is a typo. You have reviewCount.png in static/images folder and you are referring reviewCount.jpg from div tag.